# jQuery video on ended for numerous videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am showing a couple a number of videos in succession.

When the first video finishes I ask the user a question and then show another video following their response. After the second video I ask the user a final question.

The problem is that when the second video ends both `.question-one` and `.question-two` are displayed as a `block` again, as it appears the code from the first `on('ended..)` method is being triggered again.

I tried to use `unbind` to remove the binding from the videos, but this didn't work.

Here is my code below.

**HTML**

```
<video>
   <source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**JS**

```
$('.video-one').bind('ended',function(){
    $(this).removeClass('video-one');
    $(this).addClass('video-two');
    $('#video-background').css('display', 'none');
    $('.question-one').fadeIn('slow');
    $('.video-one').unbind('ended');
});

$('.question-one').click(function(){
    $('.question-one').css('display', 'none');
    $('#video-background').css('display', 'block');
    $('video').attr('src', '2.mp4'); 
});

$('.video-two').bind('ended',function(){
    $(this).removeClass('video-two');
    $(this).addClass('video-three');
    $('#video-background').css('display', 'none');
    $('.question-two').fadeIn('slow');
    $('.video-two').unbind('ended');
});
```

Is there something else that I am missing?

Comment: looks like you are removing the class before you unbind the event

Comment: @Offbeatmammal ah nice, that's a good shout...i don't have the code in front of me now, but i reckon thats it... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

instead of changing order of instructions like @Offbeatmammal said, I would suggest unbinding event based on ID of element, because you want to unbind only this one, specific - not everyone with this class probably. it's only semantic reason. you would then have to add an event parameter to your function, and get id by event.target.id if I remember well.